# CSS Animation working on Desktop Browser but not on Phone Browser. Any way to solve this?

Tags: css, html, animation

My website is https://www.timetimiri.info/ but I have some issues with my animation at the top of my page. The CSS animation works on my desktop, but when I try to load the webpage on my iPhone the animation simply does not show up. There is simply an empty space where the animation should be. This is on Safari browser and Chrome browser btw. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML (Image I animated is after the multiple /br's):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tim's Thoughts</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="The thoughts of Tim Etimiri.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Tim Etimiri ,thoughts">
<meta name="author" content="Tim Etimiri">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="darkLord.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>"Life's tragedy is that we get old too soon and wise too late" - 
Benjamin Franklin</h1>
    <h2><u>Property of Tim Etimiri.</u>
    </h2></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <img class="image" src="darkLord.png" alt="Tim's Darkest Sun." 
width="150" height="150">
    <p> "The Dark Lord"</br></br>
        My goal is to produce Great Works.</br></br>
        For what is a more Noble existence?</p>
    <div id="about">
        <p><strong>Find Me:</strong></br>
            -->Twitter: <a 
href="https://www.twitter.com/timetimiri">@timetimiri </a></br>
            -->Discord: Tim Etimiri#1511 </br>
            -->Email: timetimiri@gmail.com </br></p>
    </div>
    <h2><u>Works:</u>
        <p>
            <a href="whatIsIntelligence.html">~What Is Intelligence?</a> 
   </br></br>
            <a href="thePriceOfFreedom.html">~The Price of Freedom</a></br> 
   </br>
            <a href="theNatureOfTheWorldView.html">~The Nature of the World 
View</a>
        </p>
    </h2>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS (Animation code is at the bottom):

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #4f575a;
}
p{
margin-left: 80px;
margin-right: 300px;
margin-top: 20px;
color: rgb(216, 231, 245);
}
h2{
color: rgb(3, 104, 192);
font-size: 40px;
}
hr { 
display: block;
margin-top: 2em;
margin-bottom: 2em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style: dashed;
border-width: .5px;
width: 600px;
color: #ffffff;
}
#index strong{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  color: rgb(216, 231, 245);
}
#index hr{
display: block;
margin-top: 2em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style: dashed;
border-width: .5px;
width: 600px;
color: #ffffff;
}
h1{
  font-size: 17px;
}
#menu a{
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 19px;
padding-bottom: 22px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-left: 800px;
}
u{
color: rgb(216, 231, 245);
font-size: 35px;
}
strong{

color: rgb(216, 231, 245);
}
img{
margin-left: 80px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
#about strong{
margin-left: 0px; 
margin-right: 80px;
margin-top: 20px;
color: rgb(216, 231, 245);
}
a{
color: rgb(142, 233, 240);
}
.image {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin:-264.3px 0 0 -690px;;
-webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
animation:spin 7s linear infinite;
display: block;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Thanks for your time.

~Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resizing your browser window and you'll see what happens. The image is positioned absolute with a margin remove those two and it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realise I was setting my website up to work on my desktop screen only. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
   margin:-264.3px 0 0 -690px;
```

Its very bad coded, that wont work because you use left 50% and top 50%. That works in desktop because the desktop is wide about 1900px, the half (50%) is 950px and you margin it -690px to the left so you are able to see it. But on mobile phone you have about 360px screen width (depend on phone) , the half is 180px but you margin it -690px to the left outside of the screen.

That means, your animation is still there but pushed out of the window screen to the left.

I would say remove that line and replace left: 50% with maybe 10%

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was unaware of this. I really appreciate your efforts to help.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

remove -webkit- inside your @keyframes like this:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { transform: rotate(360deg);
transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```